# websocket: the client is not using the websocket protocol: 'upgrade' token not found in 'Connection' header

Tags: javascript, go, websocket, server

I am trying to set up a websocket connection with the server written in Go and a JavaScript frontend. I have the following files in one directory:

main.go
index.html

**This is my Go code in `main.go`: **

```
package main


import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)

var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
    ReadBufferSize:  1024,
    WriteBufferSize: 1024,
}

func homePage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "./index.html")
    conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error in handler:", err)
        return
    }
    log.Println("Client connected.")

    for {
        messageType, p, err := conn.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Fehler in ReadMessage: ", err)
            return
        }

        log.Println(string(p))

        //echo message to client
        if err := conn.WriteMessage(messageType, p); err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            return
        }
    }
}

func setupRoutes() {
    http.HandleFunc("/ws", homePage)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Server gestartet")
    setupRoutes()
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":9100", nil))

}
```

**And this is the HTML and JavaScript in index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Some unimportant html </title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <script>


        let socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9100/ws");
        console.log("Websocket started.");

        socket.onOpen = () => {
            console.log("Client started.");
        }

        socket.onclose = (event) => {
            console.log("Socket closed: ", event);
        }

        socket.onError = (error) => {
            console.log("Socket Error: ", error);
        }

        socket.onMessage = (msg) => {
            console.log(msg);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I run the thing with `go run main.go` **I get the following error:**

```
2022/11/20 16:38:33 http: superfluous response.WriteHeader call from github.com/gorilla/websocket.(*Upgrader).returnError (server.go:83)
2022/11/20 16:38:33 Error in handler: websocket: the client is not using the websocket protocol: 'upgrade' token not found in 'Connection' header
2022/11/20 16:38:33 Error in handler: write tcp [::1]:9100->[::1]:63712: wsasend: Eine bestehende Verbindung wurde softwaregesteuert durch den Hostcomputer abgebrochen.
2022/11/20 16:39:06 Error in handler: write tcp [::1]:9100->[::1]:63733: wsasend: Eine bestehende Verbindung wurde softwaregesteuert durch den Hostcomputer abgebrochen.
exit status 0xc000013a
```

The German lines mean "the existing connection was software controlled terminated by the host computer"

I am missing something and my understanding doesn't run deep enough to pinpoint what's wrong. Any help is much appreciated!

I thought maybe my JS Websocket is missing an upgrade, but in Chrome I can see the following request header for Request URL ws://localhost:9100/ws that says "Upgrade:websocket"

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Upgrade
Host: localhost:9100
Origin: http://localhost:9100
Pragma: no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Key: h3DWLuXsI9/GkTo+sIjyzw==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Upgrade: websocket
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: The homePage endpoint serves a file to the response and then attempts to use the websocket protocol on the connection.  The websocket client fails because it does not know what to do with the file response.  The server barks at you because the application indirectly calls WriteHeader multiple times.   Fix by moving `http.ServeFile(w, r, "./index.html")` out of the function to its own endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the helpful comment by Cerise Limón I was able to fix it. The problem was that I needed one endpoint for the index file and another one for the websocket. So I changed the relevant parts to this:

```
func websocketHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil) //conn is a websocket connection (aus http wird websocket protokoll)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error in handler:", err)
        return
    }
    log.Println("Client connected.")

    
    for {
        messageType, p, err := conn.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Fehler in ReadMessage: ", err)
            return
        }

        log.Println(string(p))

        //echo message to client
        if err := conn.WriteMessage(messageType, p); err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            return
        }
    }
}

func homePage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "./index.html")
}

func setupRoutes() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", homePage)
    http.HandleFunc("/ws", websocketHandler)

}
```